# " Invalid download path. Set a valid folder path to download the file. ", when using IlovePDF API

Tags: php, pdf, compression

I want to add a watermark to an existing PDF using FDPDF library and then compresse it using IlovePDF API, but i have a problem with the path of the compressed PDF, firstly this is my funtion:

```
public function updateMemoirePdf($selectedProject)
{
        set_time_limit(300);
      // Source file and watermark config 
        $file = "uploads/themes/{$selectedProject->theme}/memoire/{$selectedProject->memoire_path}"; 
        $text_image = "assets/img/te-sea-4.png"; 
        $text = 'Published by Te-sea publication'; 
        $newPdfPath = public_path("uploads/themes/{$selectedProject->theme}/memoire/{$selectedProject->memoire_path}_modified.pdf");  
        
        // Set source PDF file 

        $name = uniqid(); 
        $font_size = 3; 
        $opacity = 100; 
        $ts = explode("\n", $text); 
        $width = 0; 
        foreach($ts as $k=>$string){ 
            $width = max($width, strlen($string)); 
        } 
        $width  = imagefontwidth($font_size)*$width; 
        $height = imagefontheight($font_size)*count($ts); 
        $el = imagefontheight($font_size); 
        $em = imagefontwidth($font_size); 
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 

        $bg = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); 
        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width, $height, $bg); 

        // Font color settings 
        $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); 
        foreach($ts as $k=>$string){ 
            $len = strlen($string); 
            $ypos = 0; 
            for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){ 
                $xpos = $i * $em; 
                $ypos = $k * $el; 
                imagechar($img, $font_size, $xpos, $ypos, $string, $color); 
                $string = substr($string, 1);       
            } 
        } 
        imagecolortransparent($img, $bg); 
        $blank = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
        $tbg = imagecolorallocate($blank, 255, 255, 255); 
        imagefilledrectangle($blank, 0, 0, $width, $height, $tbg); 
        imagecolortransparent($blank, $tbg); 
        $op = !empty($opacity)?$opacity:100; 
        if ( ($op < 0) OR ($op >100) ){ 
            $op = 100; 
        } 
        
        // Create watermark image 
        imagecopymerge($blank, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $op); 
        imagepng($blank, $name.".png"); 

        $pdf = new Fpdi(); 
        if(file_exists("./".$file)){ 
            $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file); 
        }else{ 
            die('Source PDF not found!'); 
        } 
        
        // Add watermark image to PDF pages 
        for($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++){ 
            $tpl = $pdf->importPage($i); 
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpl); 
            $pdf->addPage(); 
            $pdf->useTemplate($tpl, 1, 1, $size['width'], $size['height'], TRUE); 

            $xxx_final = ($size['width']-60); 
            $yyy_final = ($size['height']-8); 
            $pdf->Image($name.'.png', $xxx_final, $yyy_final, 0, 0, 'png'); 
            
            //Put the watermark 
            $pdf->Image($text_image, 5, 5, 189); 
        } 
        @unlink($name.'.png');
        // Output PDF with watermark 
        $pdf->Output($newPdfPath, 'F');

        // Compress the PDF with watermark using ilovepdf API
        $ilovepdfPublicKey = "project_public_194707eee8c6bd80b6e1ff62702bcbe0_3d2wMd011adc7ecb22574c9c081e9f3552ade";
        $ilovepdfSecretKey = "secret_key_0b46389dbf04b99020e9d5b5a4a92162_5CkIwf291d5e2527adf6c45503ec294200819";

        $ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf($ilovepdfPublicKey, $ilovepdfSecretKey);

        $task = $ilovepdf->newTask('compress');
       
        $task->addFile($newPdfPath);

        $task->execute();
        $task->setOutputFilename('compressed_file.pdf'); // Set the output file name
// Save the compressed PDF to a file
        $compressedPdfPath = public_path("uploads/themes/{$selectedProject->theme}/memoire/{$selectedProject->memoire_path}_compressed.pdf");
        $task->download($compressedPdfPath);
        // Update the database with the path to the compressed PDF
        $selectedProject->memoire_path = "{$selectedProject->memoire_path}_compressed.pdf";
        $selectedProject->save();

        return $compressedPdfPath;


}
```

i tried placing the compressed path directly in the download function, but still the same problem,This is the code that is printed in the stacktrace

```
  * @return void

 * @throws AuthException

 * @throws PathException

 * @throws ProcessException

 * @throws UploadException

 * @throws DownloadException

 */

public function download($path = null)

{

    $this->validateTaskStarted();



    if ($path != null && !is_dir($path)) {

        if (pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == '') {

            throw new PathException('Invalid download path. Use method setOutputFilename() to set the output file name.');

        }

        throw new PathException('Invalid download path. Set a valid folder path to download the file.');

    }

    /** @psalm-suppress PossiblyNullOperand */

    $this->downloadFile($this->task);



    if (is_null($path)) $path = '.';

    /** @psalm-suppress PossiblyNullOperand */

    $destination = $path . '/' . $this->outputFileName;

    $file = fopen($destination, "w+");

    /** @psalm-suppress PossiblyNullArgument */

    fputs($file, $this->outputFile);

    fclose($file);

    return;

}



/**
```

Please i need help

Comment: Have you checked what it is you're passing in to the `download()` method? I can't guess since I have _no idea_ what your `public_path()` function returns. Is it a valid folder path? Seems like the code throws that exception if it gets a file path instead of a folder path.